# Complex exponential function and mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

So, I'm working through some questions and I've always had trouble visiualing things. In the questions were asked to sketch the image under the mapping z -> $e^z$ of the region {z E C: pi/4 ≤ Imz ≤ pi/2}. I know how to answer the question mathematically, I just don't know how to sketch the image. Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

You just take a quadratic net in the x-y plain, an give the pictures of these lines x=const<=1  and y=const in the picture plain , it shou[image]ld be circles